# Integration testing w/ nHibernate - BuildConfiguration & BuildSessionFactory are too slow

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using Fluent to add mappings from an assembly.  That takes nearly 5 seconds. Then, getting a session factory takes another 1.5. Is there anyway to get a compiled output from this guy once, and serialize it to disk:

```
Fluently.Configure(config)
                .Mappings(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Entity>()
                        .Conventions.Add(ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id"));
                })
                .BuildConfiguration();
```

We have about 15 models. Is there a faster way to do this?  I don't mind having to manually managed some cached output. A 6+ second penalty for each test class is pretty brutal.

Comment: I was able to shave about a second off by having the .hbm.xml files just loaded from disk, instead of pulled from the assembly. I'm still not close to my .1sec goal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serializing the configuration for reuse is viable:

http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/03/13/an-improvement-on-sessionfactory-initialization.html

Comment: Thanks Jay. That helped tremendously.  I don't suppose there are any tips in building a session factory?  That's now the bigger pain point.  Strangely, the time it takes to build the session factory nudged up about a quarter of a second when I switched to serialization.

Comment: Are you initializing a new session factory per test?  If so session factories are thread safe so you should be able to share this across tests.  I have a static instance of my session factory that I use across different threads.